# How do I convert a datetime with milliseconds to a string in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert:

```
5/25/2010 12:54:56:000
```

to:

```
05252010125456000
```

How do I do that in C#?

Comment: It is just a long number right? Can you just use long.ToString();?

Comment: I can't help but think that this is a bad idea.  What will you do with this string?  If you're going to store this in a database somewhere (or even a flat file), you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Hrm, there is no "youre-doing-it-wrong" tag yet

Comment: I often use strings of vaguely this sort in filenames for temp error logs (the sort that get cleaned often), images while they're being processed, that sort of thing. Hard to say it's a "bad idea" if you don't know what it's for...

Comment: I need it to be part of the fileName.

Comment: @acadia: Consider using an ISO 8601 like format, ordering the components in falling magnitude: yyyyMMddHHmmssfff = 20100525125456000. That way the file names will be sortable in date order.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). Example:

```
string formatted = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmssfff");
```

Comment: That won't get him the total count of milliseconds. Just the msec faction of the value.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using the ToString() method on your DateTime, passing a custom format string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx (I assume you currently have a DateTime object.)

Answer (score 0):

To get the total Milliseconds only as a string use this:

```
TimeSpan value = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.MinValue);
string milliseconds = value.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
```

If you want to store and/or compare the DateTime value, then I suggest you use the .Ticks property of the DateTime as a string, because you can reconstruct a DateTime value passing the ticks as a constructor argument.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood the question. The OP asked for date, time and millisecond. Notice how the example contains a date, a time and a millisecond component: 05252010125456000 = 05/25/2010 12:54:56.000.

Comment: Probably because I'm german. I can't recognize dates as such when they don't start with the day/month/year ;-)